# ruby on rails Match a url to a controller action

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to match this link `/links/128/dev?usrA=mike&usrB=carl` with my controller.

I tried using:

```
match 'links/:id/dev?usrA=:curr&usrB=:prev', to: 'links#index', via: :get
```

But it does not work.

Is there any way to match this URL with my controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
match 'links/:id/dev', to: 'links#index', via: :get
```

You don't need to be explicit while sending a `GET` request. You can send whatever you want in the GET request, and can receive in the method through the `params`.

Answer (score 1):

I generally avoid `match` and prefer the more explicit `get` (if you will only allow a `GET`)

```
get 'links/:id/dev', to: 'links#index'
```

You do not have to specify the parameters, these are parsed automatically.

Answer (score 0):

```
match '/links/:id/dev', to: 'links#index', via: :get
```

Will work fine. Everything after the "?" are considered parameters and are not considered when matching the URL.

Answer (score -1):

```
match '/links/:id/dev' => 'controller#action', :via => [:get], :as => :get_links
```

Then you can access using get_links_path() from javascript